# Getting Grade from Score Range using statistics.mean

Tags: python, statistics

I'm doing a CodeWars kata and am still new to python. The exercise requires one to complete the function so that it finds the mean of the three scores passed to it and returns the letter value associated with that grade.

I've tried to do this in my text editor and running it doesn't produce any results. I've tried to set s1,s2,s3 with various numbers prior to running the function.

Any hints or ideas? Thank you in advance.

Code as below. Apologies for the poor indenting as I'm not familiar how I may do so here.

```
import statistics
def get_grade(s1, s2, s3):
avg_grade = (statistics.mean([s1, s2, s3]))

if avg_grade <=90 and avg_grade <=100: 
    print("A")
elif avg_grade <=80 and avg_grade <=90: 
    print("B")
elif avg_grade <=70 and avg_grade <=80: 
    print("C")
elif avg_grade <=60 and avg_grade <=70: 
    print("D")
elif avg_grade <=0 and avg_grade <=60: 
    print("F")`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple minor problems, I'm pretty sure you meant `>=` instead of `<=` on the first clause of all the conditions. Also, when running a python script using `python script.py` the script needs to have a call to the method at the end in order for it to execute. Here's the revised code.

```
import statistics
def get_grade(s1, s2, s3):
    avg_grade = (statistics.mean([s1, s2, s3]))

    if avg_grade >=90 and avg_grade <=100: 
        print("A")
    elif avg_grade >= 80 and avg_grade < 90: 
        print("B")
    elif avg_grade >= 70 and avg_grade < 80: 
        print("C")
    elif avg_grade >= 60 and avg_grade < 70: 
        print("D")
    elif avg_grade >= 0 and avg_grade < 60: 
        print("F")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_grade(90, 95, 100)
```

Also, if you want to retrieve the values (in this case 90, 95, 100) from the terminal, look into `input()` and `raw_input()` [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output).